# Write org.joda.time.DateTime to DB as string instead of object?

Tags: java, postgresql, jackson, jodatime, jsonb

Right now, the following object is being written to a JSONB column in a postges db:

```
{
  "id": "custom_ 6ef7181d-6afd-4632-b867-523c9d690af4",
  "name": "bla",
  "tenantId": "test_tenant",
  "description": null,
  "lastModified": {
    "era": 1,
    "year": 2022,
    "zone": {
      "id": "Europe/London",
      "fixed": false,
      "uncachedZone": {
        "id": "Europe/London",
        "fixed": false,
        "cachable": true
      }
    },
    "millis": 1668536796965,
    "afterNow": false,
    "equalNow": false,
    "weekyear": 2022,
    "beforeNow": true,
    "dayOfWeek": 2,
    "dayOfYear": 319,
    "hourOfDay": 18,
    "yearOfEra": 2022,
    "chronology": {
      "zone": {
        "id": "Europe/London",
        "fixed": false,
        "uncachedZone": {
          "id": "Europe/London",
          "fixed": false,
          "cachable": true
        }
      }
    },
    "dayOfMonth": 15,
    "millisOfDay": 66396965,
    "minuteOfDay": 1106,
    "monthOfYear": 11,
    "secondOfDay": 66396,
    "centuryOfEra": 20,
    "minuteOfHour": 26,
    "yearOfCentury": 22,
    "millisOfSecond": 965,
    "secondOfMinute": 36,
    "weekOfWeekyear": 46
  },
  "caseSensitive": "SENSITIVE"
}
```

I'd like the `lastModified` property to be written as a string instead, so something like:

```
{
  "id": "custom_ 6ef7181d-6afd-4632-b867-523c9d690af4",
  "name": "bla",
  "tenantId": "test_tenant",
  "description": null,
  "lastModified": "2022-11-15T19:02:30.912Z",
  "caseSensitive": "SENSITIVE"
}
```

I have tried updating my DAO to use:

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat().withColonInTimeZone(true));
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything. Am I missing something else? Thanks

This is a snippet of my DAO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdDateFormat;
import com.healthmarketscience.sqlbuilder.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Component
public class AsyncResponseDao
{

    private static final String INSERT_ASYNC_RESPONSE_SQL = String.format(
        "INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s,%s,%s) VALUES (?,?,?,? :: jsonb)",
        GrammarDbSpec.asyncResponseTable.table.getName(),
        GrammarDbSpec.asyncResponseTable.tenantId.getName(),
        GrammarDbSpec.asyncResponseTable.id.getName(),
        GrammarDbSpec.asyncResponseTable.statusCode.getName(),
        GrammarDbSpec.asyncResponseTable.body.getName(),
        GrammarDbSpec.asyncResponseTable.tenantId.getName(),
        GrammarDbSpec.asyncResponseTable.id.getName());

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat().withColonInTimeZone(true));

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public void put(
        final String tenantId,
        final String id,
        final AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
    {

        // Convert AsyncResponse.body (java.lang.Object) to JSON before we insert it into the postgres JSONB column
        final String asyncResponseBodyJsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(asyncResponse.getBody());
        
        jdbcTemplate.update(
            INSERT_ASYNC_RESPONSE_SQL,
            asyncResponse.getStatusCode(),
            asyncResponseBodyJsonString,
            tenantId,
            id);
    }
}
```

And the AsyncResponse model that I'm inserting into the DB:

```
public class AsyncResponse   {
  @JsonProperty("statusCode")
  public Integer statusCode = null;

  @JsonProperty("body")
  public Object body = null;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Have you tried adding `jackson-datatype-joda` as a dependency?

Comment: @user3738870 As I recall, Jackson was long ago updated to support the *java.time* classes built into Java 8+. If I am correct, there is no need for *Joda-Time* support: *java.time* is the official successor to *Joda-Time*, both efforts led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

Comment: @BasilBourque Maybe it uses an older version of Jackson that still relies on Joda time. Based on what I've found, the JSON structure that's currently serialized is an instance from Joda time.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @user3738870, this worked:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
  .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
  .setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat().withColonInTimeZone(true))
  // We are using JodaModule to write lastModifiedDate (org.joda.time.DateTime) to the DB as a string like
  // "2022-11-15T19:02:30.912Z" rather than an object like {"era": 1, "year": 2022, "zone": ...}
  .registerModule(new JodaModule());
```